# Invoke pig with oozie - org.apache.pig.Main exit code [2]

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, mapr

I am trying to invoke a Pig action in Oozie and I am working with the following-

> - Oozie v3.3.2
> - Pig v0.12.1-mapr
> - Hadoop v1.0.3
> - mapr M5

I am able to invoke a java action using Oozie as of now. However, when I try to invoke a Pig action, its failing with an error which isn't revealing much-

```
[Map/Reduce failed, error
 message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]], after resolve [Map/Reduce failed, error
 message[Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain], exit code [2]]]
```

Looking at job logs I can infer only the following-

> - workflow has been parsed
> - oozie has invoked pig
> - job was being executed when it failed

How can I get Pig logs for this job? What is exit code [2]?

Comment: Have you check the job Tracker URL for the same, the said can be access from the Oozie Console by opening the Oozie Actiion , there you will be find ConSole URL which will be containing, the jobTracker URL Addess, which also help you to Get the Address of Pig Action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out its pretty easy to get those Pig logs. It was staring me right in the face all the time.

- Step 1 - Copy job ID for your currently running action in Oozie
- Step
  2 - Execute this `mapred job -logs <jobid>` #this will give you
  tracking URL for this job
- Step 3 - Copy paste that URL to your
  browser
- Step 4 - Dance round singing Eureka!

Comment: The command was wrong, but it did enable me to find the solution so I updated it now. In the end it would look something like this: `mapred job -logs job_1447428897416_4377`